# What do you call the value you get from a regression equation?

Tags: terminology, regression, linear-regression

Say I have 2 sets of data which I perform a linear regression on, now I have a regression equation in the form y=mx+b (for example).

Now lets say when x = 1, the observed/real value of y = 1.

So now if I use the linear regression to find a value for y when x = 1, the ____ value of y ≈ 1

---

Out of curiosity, is there a 'formal' word that would go in the blank? 'Expected' or 'Calculated' maybe?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I believe it is called the "predicted" value, and is usually written as $\hat y$.